# I am not able to change the value of a global variable when it is changed inside a library method

Tags: java, android, processing, osc

I am trying to change layout in an Android app in Processing, layouts just being 2 different methods that are run inside void draw(), but the program seems to fail to recognize the change of the currentLayout value that I am trying to change in void OscEvent.

When I print currentLayout in OscEvent, the value changes and sets to 2 as it should, but if I print it in draw() it never changes.
So this is what is happening:

- I can print "change!"
- the value of currentLayout is changed and noticed if I check it inside OscEvent()
- the value of currentLayout is NOT changed nor noticed if I check it inside draw()
- I am also able to change the value, and layout, successfully when i do it in methods that are not from the OscP5 library, I am not sure how that affects anything.

The important parts of the code:

```
public int currentLayout;

void setup() {
  currentLayout=1;//vilken scen man börjar på, kolla switchen i draw()
} 

void draw() {
  switch(currentLayout) {
  case 1:
    defaultLayout();
    break;
  case 2:
    task1();
    break;
  }
 println(currentLayout);
}
void oscEvent(OscMessage theOscMessage) {
  /* get and print the address pattern and the typetag of the received OscMessage */
 String[] list =split(theOscMessage.addrPattern(), '/');
  println(list[1]);
  if (list[1].equals("layout")) {
    println("change!");
    currentLayout=2;
  }
}
```

All help and suggestions are appreciated!
Thanks.

Comment: Are the osc functions threaded? You might be updating the variable on one thread, and not syncing it to the main UI?

Comment: Actually, I think they are! Any idea on how I should sync it to the main UI? Thanks for the answer.

Comment: I finally got it to work! With the answer of Ancantus I googled myself to this: 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2120248/how-to-synchronize-a-static-variable-among-threads-running-different-instances-o

Comment: See if that works, synchronized functions will lock a thread and let you make modifications, and hopefully update both threads on the other side. The other option would be to use a [Handler](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html) and post messages to the UI thread.

Comment: Yes I made the OscEvent synchronized, so it works well now. Thanks a lot!