# shared variable for java thread

Tags: java, multithreading, variables, shared

My program is not returning the expected output, I tried very hard but I don't know how to do for this code. What can I do ?

**Expected output**

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 ......2000
```

**Actual output**

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 1 2 3 4 5 6 ..1000
```

**Main**

```
public class Race_ConditonTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Race_Condition2 R1 = new Race_Condition2();
        Race_Condition2 R2 = new Race_Condition2();

        R1.start();
        R2.start();


   }
}
```

**RaceCondition2 (sub class)**

```
public class Race_Condition2 extends Thread{

    Race_Condition R= new Race_Condition();

    public void run() {
       R.sum();
    }   
}
```

**RaceCondition class (super class)**

```
public class Race_Condition  {
   int x=0;

   public int Load(int x){
       return x;
   }

    public void Store(int data) {
      int x= data;
      System.out.println(x);
    }

    public int Add(int i,int j) {
       return i+j ;
    }

    public void sum() {
       for (int i=0 ; i<1000 ; i++) { 
           this.x=Load(x);
           this.x=Add(x,1);
           Store(x);        
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: It's because R1 and R2 does not share x

Comment: how can i share x ?

Answer (score 0):

> how can i share x ?

simple way> make `x` **static**.

...

`static int x=0;`

...
**Edit**

After some tests, if you find something weird happening then make the Store function synchronized.

```
  public synchronized void Store(int data) {
      int x= data;
      System.out.println(x);
    }
```

check out how synchronized work [synchronized](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/syncmeth.html)

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to make the attribute x shared between R1 and R2 you could make it static in the RaceCondition class.

```
static int x=0;
```

Take care that if x is shared, they will be concurrent access to it, so some weird output could produce. Make the function that access x `synchronized` (as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2120248/how-to-synchronize-a-static-variable-among-threads-running-different-instances-o?answertab=votes#tab-top)) :

```
// static cause it only access a static field
// synchronized so the access the the shared resource is managed
public static synchronized void sum() {
   for (int i=0 ; i<1000 ; i++) { 
       this.x=Load(x);
       this.x=Add(x,1);
       Store(x);        
   }
}
```

You should probably make the same changes on the other functions.

Comment: @jameslarge that what i meant. but maybe it's unclear, i'll edit to explain better