# Question about Java synchronized

Tags: java, synchronization

The Java documentation says that "it is not possible for two invocations of synchronized methods on the same object to interleave".  What I need to know is whether synchronized will also prevent a synchronized method in two different *instances of the same class* from interleaving.

E.g. class Worker has method called process().  We have several instances of Worker running in their own threads.  We want to prevent more than one instance running the process() method simultaneously.  Will *synchronized* do this?

Thanks.

Comment: Thanks to everyone that responded!

Comment: Did they answer your question? Could you accept an answer so that we know it's done?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

No; `synchronized` only prevents multiple threads from simultaneously executing the method in the *same* instance. If you have *n* instances, there could be *n* threads, each executing the method in one of the instances.

If you need to ensure that only one thread may execute the method across all instances, you should make the method `static`, or make the method non-`synchronized` and rather use a `synchronized` block inside the method to lock on a `private static` field.

Edit: Note that synchronizing on a `private` instance variable is preferrable to having a `synchronized` method or to synchronize on `this`, and that locking on a `private static` instance variable is preferrable to having a `static synchronized` method or an instance method that synchronizes on `this.getClass()`. The reason is that `this` and `this.getClass()` are object references that are accessible throughout the program, so anybody may synchronize on these objects, and thereby block threads that want to call your method.

Edit: Also, see @Cowan's comment below - summary: if you really want to lock on the class, you might want to use `synchronized (Worker.class)` rather than `synchronized (this.getClass())`, depending on what effect you want in the case of subclassing.

Comment: More importantly, you shouldn't synchronize on `this.getClass()` for another reason - it won't work in the presence of inheritance! If class Worker has two child classes, FooWorker and BarWorker, then invocations of .process() will take different locks when invoked on an instance of FooWorker vs. an instance of BarWorker.

Agree that the `private static` variable is a better idea, but if you DO  want to synchronize on the class, be explicit: `synchronized(Worker.class)`

Answer (score 4):

No, synchronized will not do this. More specifically synchronized on the instance level will not do this. Instead you will have to synchronize on the class level.

For example instead of having:

```
public synchronized method()
{
    //do stuff
}
```

You will have to code as:

```
public void method()
{
    synchronized(this.getClass())
    {
        //do stuff
    }
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't synchronize on `this.getClass()` because that object is also available to the rest of the code - which means that if some other part of the code decides to synchronize on `TheClass.class`, calls to `method()` will be blocked (unless you really want that behaviour). Better to synchronize on a `private static` variable.

Answer (score 2):

Not unless the method is `static`. A `synchronized` non-static method takes a lock on the object (instance) on which it is invoked, not on the class.

A synchronized static method takes a lock on the class, so that could help - but it's often not very practical.

What you could do is have a static member object in your class, and do a synchronized block on that (class-global) object in your `process` method.

Answer (score 2):

No, the method synchronized locks on the specific object (the 'this'), so 2 instances of the same class would lock on different objects.

If you want to synchronize across all instances of a class, you need to use a synchronized block IN the method, locking on a static final object.

Answer (score 0):

If you make the method `process` static, it would only allow one invocation of the method at the same time.

If that is not possible, have a static variable, say `Integer lock`;
And use `synchronized (lock)` inside your method `process`.
that is

```
process()
{
    synchronized (lock)
    {

        // all your code

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I slightly disagree with Aasmund -- though agree a bit at the same time:
If you use a construct like this:

```
class Worker {
...
 public synchronized void process() {...}
}
```

then Aasmund is right -- that won't prevent multiple instances of the `Worker` class to execute `process()` in parallel.
However, you can use the `synchronized` keyword still to synchronize on a static member to prevent that from happening:

```
class Worker {
 static Object o = new Object();
 ...
 public void process() {
  synchronized(o) {
   ...//perform the work here
  }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Only one thread can hold a lock on an object at any one time.

A synchronized method attempt to hold a lock on the instance. Another thread can also hold a lock on another instance of the same class.  Another thread cannot enter another synchronized method of the same instance. i.e. it is not the method which is locked.

However a thread can enter a non-synchronized method while another thread holds a lock on that object. Only synchronized methods are protected.

A static synchronized method obtains a lock on the Class rather than the object. However, the follows the same rules as non-static method except with a different object.

Note: There is no "instance" for static method even though you can write code which appears to use an instance. e.g. `instance.staticMethod()`