# Adding numbers using multiple threads in java

Tags: java, multithreading, parallel-processing, calculator

I am having trouble figuring out what my code is doing as this is my first time coding using multiple threads. To start off, in attempt to learn this type of programming I decided to write a miniature program that uses 8 threads to sum a number. However, no matter what I do it seems as if my program never stops when count = 10, it continues onward. I am using 8 threads as I planned on expanding my program to do large calculations. However, these threads are not correlating at all. They are going way past 10. I have used a synchronized method. I have tried a lock. I have tried implementing both at the same time. No matter what, it appears as if the threads still calculate past 10. See below for my current code.

```
public class calculator implements Runnable {

static int counter = 0;
static int sum = 0;

private synchronized static int getAndIncrement()
{
//  System.out.println("counter is  : " + counter);

    int temp = counter;
    counter = counter + 1;
    System.out.println("counter is now : " + counter);
    return temp;
}

private synchronized void addToSum(int value)
{
//  System.out.println("sum : " + sum + " value: " + value);
    sum += value;
}

@Override
public void run() 
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    while(counter < 10)
    {
        int tempVal = getAndIncrement();
        System.out.println("temp val : " + tempVal);
        addToSum(tempVal);
    //  System.out.println("sum is now : " + sum);

    }

}


}
```

This is my main method:

```
    public static void main(String[] args)
{


    calculator[] calc = new calculator[8];
    Thread[] thread = new Thread[8];

    final long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

    for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
    {
        calc[i] = new calculator();
        thread[i] = new Thread(calc[i]);
        thread[i].start();
    }

    while(thread[0].isAlive() ||thread[1].isAlive() || thread[2].isAlive() || thread[3].isAlive() || thread[4].isAlive() || thread[5].isAlive() || thread[6].isAlive() || thread[7].isAlive())
    {}

    final long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    System.out.println(calculator.sum);
    System.out.println("Execution time : " + (startTime - endTime));
}
```

I appreciate the help!

Comment: You must use atomic integer for counter or locked the block in which you're using it.

Comment: Also, instead of using the while checking isAlive, you can call the join function of each thread.

Comment: @mahdi_12167 I will try atomic integers. I am just a bit puzzled because I thought synchronization kept more than one thread from gaining access to a method at a time? I also tried locking the variable following a different stack overflow thread, however, I still had the same issue.

Comment: @mahdi_12167 The atomic integer works. I appreciate the tip, i'll swap over to calling the join :).

Comment: You right, but you should pay attention to the fact that the synchronized function only prevents multiple threads from simultaneously executing the method in the same instance.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6214229/question-about-java-synchronized

Comment: If you want to use a lock, you should an object as lock whose scope is analogous to the counter.

Comment: @mahdi_12167 Thank you, it makes sense now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `synchronized` keyword takes the *object*
 lock. This means that two methods that are `synchronized` cannot execute *on the same object*. They will, however, execute concurrently on invocation on 2 different objects.

In your example, your code had 8 objects of `calculator`. The `synchronized` methods do not help you. Each thread uses it's separate object. You can completely remove the `synchronized` keyword, and your code will be semantically equivalent.

To avoid this, use the atomic version of the objects (`AtomicInt`) or lock on the objects themselves: `synchronized(counter){...}` but for this to work you will have to change the type to `Integer`.

Answer (score 0):

I've just tested your sample and found the addToSum method doesn't work as expected here with heavy multi-thread, even if [synchronized](/questions/tagged/synchronized) keyword is present.

Here, as sum variable is [static](/questions/tagged/static), the method can be made [static](/questions/tagged/static) too.

After adding the [static](/questions/tagged/static) keyword, the behavior is as expected:

```
    private static synchronized void addToSum(int value)
    {
        sum += value;
    }
```

Here a simple test (addToSum replaced by incSum for simplicity) :

```
    class IncrementorThread implements Runnable {
        private static int sum = 0;
        private static synchronized void incSum()
        {
            sum ++;
        }
        public void run() {
            incSum();
            Thread.yield();
        }
    }

    void testIncrementorThread1() {
        ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
        //ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor() // result always ok without needing concurrency precaution
        for(int i = 0; i < 5000; i++)
            executorService.execute(new IncrementorThread());
        executorService.shutdown();
        executorService.awaitTermination(4000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
        System.out.println("res = "+IncrementorThread.sum); // must be 5000
    }
```

Result must be 5000, which is not the case if we remove the [static](/questions/tagged/static) keyword from the method incSum()