# How to model a situation, when i++ is corrupted by simultaneously executing threads?

Tags: java, multithreading, atomic

If int incrementing/decrementing operations are not atomic in Java 6, that is, they are said to be performed in several steps (read the value, increment, write etc), I would like to see a piece of code that will demonstrate how multiple threads can affect a single int variable in a way that will corrupt it entirely.

For example, elementary steps include, but not cover all, these:
i++ ~= put i to the register; increment i (inc asm operation); write i back to memory;

if two or more threads interleave during the process, that would probably mean that the value after two consequent calls to i++ will be incremented only once.

Can you demonstrate a piece of code in java that models this situation in multithreading environment?

Comment: If you need this for some actual program, just synchronize access to any data shared between threads. If you need it for some study, then I can't help.

Comment: according to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1006655 are `int` operations atomic (while e.g. `long` operations *may* be atomic)

Comment: `int` read/write operations are atomic, however `++` is not atomic.

Comment: Yes, but also note even if they are atomic, they might not be visible across threads - at least `volatile` is needed.

Comment: @Tomasz Nurkiewicz Could you explain "might not be visible across threads". May it result in data ovewriting, like in above example or it's just a reading problem ?

Comment: See [this](http://jeremymanson.blogspot.com/2008/11/what-volatile-means-in-java.html) article, also there are several question on SO about `volatile`. Ont thread writes to the variable but other threads still see the old value - so it might corrupt your data in some circumstances.

Comment: @ Tomasz Nurkiewicz Overall I conclude that atomic operations are guaranteed to be seen among threads only with volatile keyword. Still, volatile does not resolve an issue with non-atomic operations, as i++. Correct ?

Answer (score 3):

```
public class Test {
    private static int counter;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        Runnable r = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++) {
                    counter++;
                }
            }
        };
        Thread t1 = new Thread(r);
        Thread t2 = new Thread(r);
        t1.start();
        t2.start();
        t1.join();
        t2.join();
        if (counter != 200000) {
            System.out.println("Houston, we have a synchronization problem: counter should be 200000, but it is " + counter);
        }
    }
}
```

Running this program on my machine gives

```
Houston, we have a synchronization problem: counter should be 200000, but it is 198459
```

Comment: Can you print the results you see as the first thread can complete before the second one starts. (See my answer)

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code. Sorry for the `static`, just wanted to save few lines of code, it does not affect the results:

```
public class Test
{
    public static int value;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException
    {
        Runnable r = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                for(int i = 0; i < 50000; ++i)
                    ++value;
            }
        };

        List<Thread> threads = new ArrayList<Thread>();
        for(int j = 0; j < 2; ++j)
            threads.add(new Thread(r));
        for (Thread thread : threads)
            thread.start();
        for (Thread thread : threads)
            thread.join();

        System.out.println(value);
    }
}
```

This program can print anything between 50000 and 100000, but it never actually printed 100000 on my machine.

Now replace `int` with `AtomicInteger` and `incrementAndGet()` method. It will always print 100000 without big performance impact (it uses CPU CAS instructions, no Java synchronization).

Comment: Great example you provided. :)

Comment: Can you print the results you see as the first thread can complete before the second one starts. (See my answer)

Comment: Interestingly enough, if you join the two loops (start(), join() in one block), you will get exactly the opposite effect, the counter value would be as expected.

Comment: *@Peter Lawrey*: on my computer (4-core desktop) these values are enough to show the problem (sometimes I got results only slightly higher than 50000...)

Comment: *@EugeneP*: nothing actually interesting in this case: by calling `start()` and `join()` alternately you are actually running only one thread at a time - spawning the first one and waiting until it finishes, then spawning a second... No concurrency - no race conditions.

Answer (score 1):

You need to run the test for many iterations as `++` is quick and can run to completion before there is time for there to be a problem.

```
public static void main(String... args) throws InterruptedException {
    for (int nThreads = 1; nThreads <= 16; nThreads*=2)
        doThreadSafeTest(nThreads);
}

private static void doThreadSafeTest(final int nThreads) throws InterruptedException {
    final int count = 1000 * 1000 * 1000;

    ExecutorService es = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(nThreads);
    final int[] num = {0};
    for (int i = 0; i < nThreads; i++)
        es.submit(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                for (int j = 0; j < count; j += nThreads)
                    num[0]++;
            }
        });
    es.shutdown();
    es.awaitTermination(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    System.out.printf("With %,d threads should total %,d but was %,d%n", nThreads, count, num[0]);
}
```

prints

```
With 1 threads should total 1,000,000,000 but was 1,000,000,000
With 2 threads should total 1,000,000,000 but was 501,493,584
With 4 threads should total 1,000,000,000 but was 319,482,716
With 8 threads should total 1,000,000,000 but was 261,092,117
With 16 threads should total 1,000,000,000 but was 202,145,371
```

with only 500K I got the following on a basic laptop. On a faster machine you can have a higher iteration count before a problem would be seen.

```
With 1 threads should total 500,000 but was 500,000
With 2 threads should total 500,000 but was 500,000
With 4 threads should total 500,000 but was 500,000
With 8 threads should total 500,000 but was 500,000
With 16 threads should total 500,000 but was 500,000
```