# Example of exception in ArrayList?

Tags: java, multithreading, collections

I am using ArrayList and I want an example of Exception in case if multiple threads try to access the same list without synchronization ? I done this in single threaded application in which if we remove an element from list while iteration it throws ConcurrentModificationExceptoin but I want to achieve the same in multi threaded environment. If anyone could give me an example of that would be highly appreciated ?

```
package com.test2;

public class ThreadTest extends Thread {

    List list = new ArrayList<String>();

    @Override
    public void run() {

        list.add("1");
        list.add("2");
        list.add("3");
        list.add("4");
        list.add("5");
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        list.add("6");
        list.add("7");
        list.add("8");

        Iterator<String> it = list.iterator();
        while (it.hasNext()) {
            System.out.println(it.next());
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {



        Thread th1 = new ThreadTest();
        Thread th2 = new ThreadTest();
        Thread th3 = new ThreadTest();
        th1.start();
        th2.start();
        th3.start();
        try {
            th1.join();
            th2.join();
            th3.join();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }




    }

}
```

Comment: better to share your code as well.

Comment: are you asking about how to solve this ConcurrentModificationExceptoin?

Comment: Braj : I am asking how to get an exception in multithreaded environment

Comment: in the same way as you are doing in single threaded enviornment.

Comment: Braj : code added.No, I want to get an exception using this code becuase we say we cannot use ArrayList in the Multithreaded environment. So I am trying to achieve that...

Comment: Make sure the threads are accessing the *same* list.

Comment: you might want a `for(int i=0; i<1000000; i++) { list.add(i); }` there, instead of just 8 elements and hoping to create a concurrent threading problem.

Comment: Mike 'Pomax' Kamermans- done as you suggested but it worked fine. it took some time, but got no exceptions.

Comment: @Peter - Are you on a multi-core machine? You might not going to get threading issues if you don't actually have hardware that can run multiple threads concurrently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're accessing a separate list instance in each of your threads. Since each list is only accessed by one thread, you can't get a concurrency error.

```
List list = new ArrayList<String>();
```

That declares an *instance field*. Therefore, each call to `new ThreadTest()` creates a new list. In order to make all the `ThreadTest` instances use the same list, try making the field `static` (i.e. a *class field*):

```
static List list = new ArrayList<String>();
```

As for *how* an error can happen, take a look at [the code for `ArrayList`'s `add` method](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7-b147/java/util/ArrayList.java#410):

```
 public boolean add(E e) {
     ensureCapacityInternal(size + 1);  // Increments modCount!!
     elementData[size++] = e;
     return true;
 }
```

If two threads call `add` at the same time, they could process the `elementData[size++] = e` statement at the same time. [The `size` field is not declared `volatile`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7-b147/java/util/ArrayList.java#118); therefore, the two threads could end up writing to the same index in the `elementData` array.

Even if `size` were declared `volatile`, the `size++` operation is *not atomic*. See *[How to model a situation, when i++ is corrupted by simultaneously executing threads?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7037268)* for an example of how an operation like `size++` can fail in a multithreaded environment.

Finally, if you don't understand what `volatile` and atomic mean in the Java context, you really need to read up on concurrent programming in Java before you write any multithreaded code. It will be a worthwhile investment as you'll save yourself a lot of headaches by understanding these concepts.

Comment: Thanks a lot DaoWen. after adding static I am getting exception.

Answer (score 1):

Quick answer:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException
    {
        final ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        list.add("Item 1");
        list.add("Item 2");
        list.add("Item 3");
        list.add("Item 4");

        Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable()
        {
            @Override
            public void run ()
            {
                for (String s : list)
                {
                    System.out.println(s);
                    try
                    {
                        Thread.sleep(1000);
                    }
                    catch (InterruptedException e)
                    {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        });
        thread.start();

        Thread.sleep(2000);
        list.remove(0);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Item 1
Item 2
Exception in thread "Thread-0" java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
    at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.checkForComodification(ArrayList.java:859)
    at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.next(ArrayList.java:831)
    at com.akefirad.tests.Main$1.run(Main.java:34)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Note:
As @Braj and @DaoWen said you are using different instances. Either use their suggestions or pass the list variable in the constructor of your class (ThreadTest).

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, yes change this

```
List list = new ArrayList<String>();
```

by using [`Collections.synchronizedList(List)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#synchronizedList%28java.util.List%29) to something like (**and** don't use [raw types](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/rawTypes.html)),

```
List<String> list = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<String>());
```

From the javadoc,

> Returns a synchronized (thread-safe) list backed by the specified list. In order to guarantee serial access, it is critical that all access to the backing list is accomplished through the returned list.
>
> It is imperative that the user manually synchronize on the returned list when iterating over it:
>
> ```
> List list = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList());
> ...
> synchronized (list) {
>   Iterator i = list.iterator(); // Must be in synchronized block
>   while (i.hasNext())
>     foo(i.next());
>   }
> }
> ```

Comment: Thanks for the code Elliott Frisch, but I am trying to get an exception. I am doing POC on Java Doc statement "If we use ArrayList in Multithreaded environment we'll get an concurrent exception."

Answer (score 0):

> it throws ConcurrentModificationExceptoin but I want to achieve the same in multi threaded environment
>
> I am asking how to get an exception in multithreaded environment - From comment

Since you are creating separate copy of `List` for each thread hence there is no chance to get this exception.

Just make the `List` as **shared resource** then you will encounter this exception:

sample code:

```
public class Main{

    public static void main(String[] args){

        // shared by all the threads.
        final List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        
        class ThreadTest extends Thread {


            @Override
            public void run() {

                list.add("1");
                list.add("2");
                list.add("3");
                list.add("4");
                list.add("5");
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                list.add("6");
                list.add("7");
                list.add("8");

                Iterator<String> it = list.iterator();
                while (it.hasNext()) {
                    System.out.println(it.next());
                }

            }
        }

        Thread th1 = new ThreadTest();
        Thread th2 = new ThreadTest();
        Thread th3 = new ThreadTest();
        th1.start();
        th2.start();
        th3.start();
        try {
            th1.join();
            th2.join();
            th3.join();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Exception in thread "Thread-2" java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
    at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.checkForComodification(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.next(Unknown Source)
    at com.test.TestDemo$1ThreadTest.run(TestDemo.java:390)
```

Comment: Braj : Could you tell me where are you declaring your list ?

Comment: just outside the class `ThreadTest` to make it shared resources.

Comment: I am afraid that we can declare a list outside the class in Java. It's giving compilation error. Are you sure we can declare the list outside the class in Java ?

Comment: Don't know how are you doing it, I have shared a running code.