# Is it thread-safe to lazily initialize references if the written value is always the same?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, volatile

In my application, I need to set a variable lazily since I don't have access to the necessary methods during class initialization, but I also need that value to be accessible across multiple threads. I know that I could use [double-checked locking](https://www.cs.umd.edu/~pugh/java/memoryModel/DoubleCheckedLocking.html) to solve this, but it seems like overkill. **The method that I need to call to obtain the value is idempotent and the return value will never change.** I'd like to lazily initialize the reference as if I were in a single-threaded environment. It seems like this should work since reads and writes to references are atomic.[[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3463658/are-64-bit-assignments-in-java-atomic-on-a-32-bit-machine)][[2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.7)]

Here's some example code for what I'm doing.

```
// views should only be accessed in getViews() since it is
// lazily initialized. Call getViews() to get the value of views.
private List<String> views;

/* ... */

private List<String> getViews(ServletContext servletContext) {

    List<String> views = this.views;

    if (views == null) {

        // Servlet Context context and init parameters cannot change after
        // ServletContext initialization:
        // https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#setInitParameter(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)
        String viewsListString = servletContext.getInitParameter(
                "my.views.list.VIEWS_LIST");
        views = ListUtil.toUnmodifiableList(viewsListString);
        this.views = views;
    }

    return views;
}
```

[This question about 32-bit primitives is similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9103449/thread-safe-without-volatile), but I want to confirm that the behavior is the same for references to objects like `String`s and `List`s.

Seemingly this should work fine since each thread will either see `null` and recompute value (not a problem since the value never changes) or see the already computed value. Am I missing any pitfalls here? Is this code thread-safe?

Comment: Without synchronization (synch block or volatile) you might end up with every thread having its own instance of list (every thread could see that `views == null` and initialize variable and use its own copy of the list)

Comment: Access to references and primitives is atomic.  The issues with atomic access to 64-bit values was resolved from Java 5.0

Comment: Under this implementation, each thread could end up with a different instance of `views`. Is that okay?

Comment: @erickson, ah I didn't really think about that, technically all those instances would contain equivalent data, but I guess that could cause potential memory issues. For the sake of the question, let's assume that each thread getting it's own instance is okay, but I'm glad to take that pitfall into account. Thanks!

Comment: @stiemannkj1 String's hash is a lazily initialized, 32-bit value without volatile semantics since racing computations have the same result. However it is usually not worth such tricks unless isolated to extremely safe, performance critical code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Your code is not necessarily thread-safe**. Although "[w]rites to and reads of references are always atomic...,"[[1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se9/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.7)] the Java Memory Model provides no guarantee that the object will be completely initialized when referenced by other threads. The Java Memory Model only guarantees that an object's `final` fields will be initialized before any threads can see a reference to it:

> A thread that can only see a reference to an object after that object has been completely initialized is guaranteed to see the correctly initialized values for that object’s final fields.

[JSR-133: Java Memory Model and Thread Specification](http://www.cs.umd.edu/%7Epugh/java/memoryModel/jsr133.pdf)

So if the implementation of `ListUtil.toUnmodifiableList(viewsListString);` returns a `List` object that has any non-final fields, it's possible that other threads will see the `List` reference before the non-final fields are initialized.

---

So for example, let's say the implementation of `toUnmodifiableList()` method was something like:

```
public static List<String> toUnmodifiableList(final String viewsString) {
    return new AbstractList<String>() {
        String[] viewsArray = viewsString.split(",");
        @Override
        public String get(final int index) {
            return viewsArray[index];
        }
    };
}
```

Thread A calls `getViews(servletContext)` and finds `views` to be `null` so it attempts to initialize `views`.

During the call to `toUnmodifiableList()`, the JVM performs an optimization and reorders the instructions so that the following execution occurs:

```
views = /* Reference to AbstractList<String> prior to initialization */
this.views = views;
/* new AbstractList<String>() occurs and viewsString.split(",") completes */
```

While Thread A is executing, Thread B calls `getViews(servletContext)` after Thread A executes `this.views = views;` but before `viewsString.split(",")` completes.

Now Thread B has a reference to `this.views` where `this.views.viewsArray` is `null`, so any calls to `this.views.get(index)` will result in a `NullPointerException`.

---

In order to ensure thread-safety, any object returned by `getViews()` would need to ensure that it has only `final` fields in order to guarantee that no threads ever see a partially initialized object (or you could ensure that uninitialized values are handled correctly in the object, but that is likely not possible). I believe you would need to ensure that all `Object` references within the object returned by `getViews()` also have only `final` fields as well. So if you returned a `List` that contained a `final` reference to `MyClass`, you would need to make sure that all of `MyClass`'s members are `final` too.

For more information, check out: [Partial constructed objects in the Java Memory Model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45857765/partial-constructed-objects-in-the-java-memory-model#45858064).

Answer (score 0):

> This question about 32-bit primitives is similar, but I want to confirm that the behavior is the same for references to objects like Strings and Lists.

Yes, because writing references is always atomic [per the JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se9/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.7):

> Writes to and reads of references are always atomic, regardless of whether they are implemented as 32-bit or 64-bit values.

[Peter Lawrey notes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50495123/is-it-thread-safe-to-lazily-initialize-references-if-the-written-value-is-always/50495231#comment88003172_50495123) that this is valid from Java 5 onward.

But note [Ivan's observation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50495123/is-it-thread-safe-to-lazily-initialize-references-if-the-written-value-is-always/50495231#comment88003158_50495123):

> Without synchronization (synch block or volatile) you might end up with every thread having its own instance of list (every thread could see that `views == null` and initialize variable and use its own copy of the list)

...and [erickson's question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50495123/is-it-thread-safe-to-lazily-initialize-references-if-the-written-value-is-always/50495231#comment88003176_50495123):

> Under this implementation, each thread could end up with a different instance of `views`. Is that okay?

Comment: The last statement is true from Java 5.0

Comment: @PeterLawrey - Thanks! I didn't know it had ever not been true. I did use Java pre 5 (Java 1.0, in fact), but the first time I had to know this must have been after Java 5 wa sout. :-)

Comment: Pre Java 5.0 it was implementation dependant for 64-bit primitives, however the x64 version happened to be atomic which means you were even less likely to come across the issue.