# Java Array write/read operations

Tags: java, arrays

Are Array read/writes atomic in nature?

```
int[] arr = new int[10];
int[8] = 4; // This is what I'm interested in
```

In the above code, the second line should generate two Machine Instructions like

```
reg1 = reg_containing_arr_address + 32
Memcopy reg1 4
```

Some [posts](http://www.google.com/url?q=http%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fquestions%2F28728307%2Fjava-editing-array-from-multiple-threads&sa=D&sntz=1&usg=AFQjCNG1mZ-PFiCE1NXG5opkY9QGAS5I0A) on stack overflow saw that these are atomic. Can anyone explain me how they are?

Comment: I know this does not specifically address your question, but check out the package java.util.concurrent.atomic (Java 8).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The components (elements) of arrays are variables.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.10.3)

> The result of an array access expression is a variable of type `T`, namely the variable within the array selected by the value of the index expression.

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1006655/are-java-primitive-ints-atomic-by-design-or-by-accident), writes and reads of `int` variables are atomic. Since your array is of type `int`, reads and writes to it are atomic.

Comment: I clearly understand that `int` variables are atomic, and read/writes to that variable are atomic (i.e. the second instruction in my generated machine code). But there is one more instruction of generating the variable's address in setting the array's value. I really don't think this explains how and what atomic instruction is generated when setting the array value.

Comment: @iRaviiVooda In your example instructions, `reg1` is effectively a constant/immutable. It will never change. So it's basically just `memcopy <addr> 4`.

Comment: I'm exactly looking for what you are saying. With my knowledge, I don't see how it is a constant. Lookup in arrays is O(1), but its actually 2 instructions like I showed. Can you tell me the instructions generated for my instruction?

Comment: @iRaviiVooda Conceptually, it's as if the first instruction didn't exist. It's impossible (failing a buggy OS) that `reg1` can be different between the first and second instructions.