# Atomicity and memory order in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization, atomic, memory-model

I'm new to Java and is currently reading the book *Java: A Beginner's Guide, 6th Edition*. I come across some confusions with respect to atomicity and memory order in Java.

In the examples of the book that involving multithreading, concurrent access to shared resources (e.g., a shared variable) is not synchronized, nor are the shared resources specifically marked (e.g, atomic or volatile or something like that). For instance, in **Try This 15-1** (page 519), concurrent access to the shared variable `stopFlag` is not serialized nor is the variable specifically marked either.

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1006655/are-java-primitive-ints-atomic-by-design-or-by-accident/1006712#1006712), certain data types in Java are guaranteed to be atomic even if they are not specifically marked. This somewhat solves the consideration concerning atomicity. But how about memory order? Does the default treatment imply sequential-consistency like the default [`memory_order_seq_cst`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/memory_order) treatment on access to atomic types in C++?

Following are some critical code snippet from the example.

```
public class Banner extends Applet implements Runnable {
  String msg = " Java Rules the Web ";
  Thread t;
  boolean stopFlag;
  // Initialize t to null.
  public void init() {
    t = null;
  }

  // Start thread
  public void start() {
    t = new Thread(this);
    stopFlag = false;
    t.start();
  }

  // Entry point for the thread that runs the banner.
  public void run() {
    // Redisplay banner
    for( ; ; ) {
      try {
        repaint();
        Thread.sleep(250);
        if(stopFlag) break;
      } catch(InterruptedException exc) {}
    }
  }

  // Pause the banner.
  public void stop() {
    stopFlag = true;
    t = null;
  }

  // Display the banner.
  public void paint(Graphics g) {
    char ch;
    ch = msg.charAt(0);
    msg = msg.substring(1, msg.length());
    msg += ch;
    g.drawString(msg, 50, 30);
  }
```

Comment: Can you paste in the code you are talking about (if it is not too long)?

Comment: @Thilo Some code snippet added.

Comment: Nope, this code is not actually thread-safe.  Even if it came from a book, that does not mean it is not full of crap.

Comment: @LouisWasserman I was hoping I were wrong and the examples are correct :(

Comment: the code invokes `repaint` in a non-event thread, which is very unsafe.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No.

If you use data structures like `AtomicInteger`, then yes, `set()` operation implies a strong memory order, just like some other operations in the class. The word "Atomic" is used here to express that the class implement a set of atomic operations (e.g. `compareAndSet`) that ordinarily would be composed of sub-operations. Incidentally, these kind of data structures often follow strong memory orders, and by word association, "atomic", used in this kind of context, often implies strong memory order. (But not always true though, e.g. `lazySet`  and `weakCompareAndSet` in `AtomicInteger`)

Back to your question, the word "atomic" there has no such connotation, it simply means the write is indivisible. But that is meaningless. What is meaningful is to say that a write to a non-volatile `long` or `double` variable is "non-atomic" because it is equivalent to two writes  [(JLS#17.7)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.7). Other writes are not-non-atomic.

Comment: Your answer agrees with my understanding and expectations :) In C++, the difference is that when applying operations on atomic types, you have a choice as to what kind of memory order (fence) to impose (with the most strict sequential-consistency being default).

Comment: This article (http://www.infoq.com/articles/memory_barriers_jvm_concurrency) seems to confirm this point. Gonna accept this answer.

Comment: see also section#6 of this paper - http://soft.vub.ac.be/races/wp-content/uploads/2012/09/races2012_submission_3.pdf

Answer (score 3):

As the answer you linked explains, atomicity and visibility are completely different concepts.  Atomicity of ints insures that if a thread changes an `int` value from 5 to -7, other threads may observe either 5 or -7 but never anything else.

Visibility deals with *when* the other threads are guaranteed to see that the variable changed from 5 to -7.

The example in your book is probably meant to illustrate that unless `stopFlag` variable is declared as `volatile`, its modification from one thread may become visible to other threads right away or some indeterminate time later or even never.

Comment: In C++, the common practice to impose memory order is through access to atomic variables (though you can, technically, place thread fences independently, but it is rarely used). So, atomicity and memory order are related at least in C++. The example is to illustrate the basic structure of a Java applet.

Comment: java memory model is a complex enough beast without trying to superimpose it in your mind onto C++ memory model.  The terms don't mean the same thing.  There are no atomic variables in java although there are classes like `AtomicInteger` that wrap around `volatile` variables and provide a nice API to work with them.

Comment: @Lingxi If that example in the book is to illustrate how you are supposed to write thread-safe code, get a better book.  "Effective Java" is a fantastic all-around Java book.  If you are especially interested in concurrency and memory model, "Java Concurrency in Practice" has all the information you will ever need.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. I will look into those books.

Comment: @Lingxi, in C++ this practice works because the designers gave atomic variables additional semantics such that operations are sequentially consistent by default. This doesn't have to be the case in every language, it's not even the case in C++ if you explicitly pick other consistency models. See - http://bartoszmilewski.com/2008/12/01/c-atomics-and-memory-ordering/