# volatile declaration on int primitive type

Tags: java, concurrency, atomic, volatile

I am quoting from Oracle's Java documentation on [Atomic Access](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/atomic.html)

> - Reads and writes are atomic for reference variables and for most primitive variables (all types except long and double).
> - Reads and writes are atomic for all variables declared `volatile` (including long and double variables).

I understand how `volatile` works. But mentioning the requirement to declare `volatile` explicitly for `long` and `double` variables to get atomic access in the second statement, is making `volatile` declaration for reference variables and for most primitive variables (all types except long and double) in the first statement optional.

But I am seeing codes which use explicit `volatile` declaration in `int` primitive type to achieve atomic access; and not doing so not guaranteeing atomic access.

```
int variable1;          // no atomic access
volatile int variable2; // atomic access
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: [Atomicity is very different to volatility...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1006655/are-java-primitive-ints-atomic-by-design-or-by-accident#answer-1006712) `volatile` keyword in the last line is used for a visibility purpose (not for atomicity).

Comment: @Oleksandr that link definitely helped. But I was actually mixing up atomicity and visibility which I got cleared up from the answers.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The first statement does not refer to making reference variables and primitive variables (except `long` and `double`) **`volatile`**.

It says *reads* and *writes* of all reference variables and all primitives except `long` and `double` are **atomic** (by default). To make *reads* and *writes* of `long` and `double` **atomic** they need to be `volatile`.

Atomicity does not have anything to do with *visibility*.

The following paragraph on the same doc

> Atomic actions cannot be interleaved, so they can be used without fear of thread interference. However, this does not eliminate all need to synchronize atomic actions, because memory consistency errors are still possible. Using volatile variables reduces the risk of memory consistency errors, because any write to a volatile variable establishes a happens-before relationship with subsequent reads of that same variable.

So, statements like `a = 1` where `a` is an `int` (for example) are *atomic* but you still need to have *volatile* if you want the assignment to be visible for any *subsequent* reading threads.

Reading/Writing to a long/double variable is a compound action and making it *volatile* ensures that it is atomic.

Answer (score 6):

The `volatile` keyword does more than guarantee atomic access, it also comes with **visibility guarantees**.

As `double` and `long` primitives take twice the space of an `int` (64 bits) updating their values can happen in two 32 bit chunks. As such, without volatile, you could see the value of the `long` or `double` in between those two steps. This is not the case for other primitive variables.

But atomic access is not the same as visibility. The `volatile` keyword also guarantees that all reads of the variable on other threads that happen after a write to it, will see the new value. So that's why the use of `volatile` on other primitive types can still be needed.

> When a field is declared volatile, the compiler and runtime
>   are put on notice that this variable is shared and that operations on it should not
>   be reordered with other memory operations. Volatile variables are not cached in
>   registers or in caches where they are hidden from other processors, so a read of a
>   volatile variable always returns the most recent write by any thread.

*Java Concurrency in Practice : 3.1.4 Volatile variables*